# How to reload the entire page from an ajax response?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, response, reload

I have a web page generated with php with a form placed within a div. The form is submitted using Ajax and validated on the server side. If there is an error, the contents of the div is replaced with an updated form with error messages. If the form has no errors in it, I want to reload the entire page from the ajax response, not just the div. 
Does anyone know how to do that? 
I have tried sending location header but it places the new page in the div. I have also tried javascript window.location but I don't know hot to get it executed when the ajax response has been received. I am not using jQuery so I want to do this in plan javascript and/or php.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use Ajax, why do you want to reload the page?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do that in your callback as follows:

```
location.reload(true);
```

Honestly, that kind of defeats the purpose of doing something asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, it lead me in the right direction. I use Ajax for validation of the entire form. In case the form data is OK I want to display the updated item and then it is more convenient for me to redraw the entire page because I want other parts of the page to update as well. To redraw the page I send an URL in the HTTP response and then I check the response string. If it includes a URL i use window.location, otherwise I replace innerHTML.